# How to send data from a client to my server without fake data?

Tags: java, php

How can I send data from a client (user) to my server safely without the possibility of fake data being sent to my server then into my database?

For example, let's say I made a program that plays a game and I want it to track stats of my user.

The game is redistributed with code to track the users progress then sends their progress to my server.

With this in mind, how can I prevent users from sending FAKE data to my server by decompiling my program and checking what the code was to send data to my server

Comment: That is really, really hard to prevent 100% reliably.  Even modern games suffer from this issue at times.  There are techniques to make it harder to decompile your program.

Comment: Don't trust user's input. Never.

Answer (score 1):

Make the game server authoritative, meaning the client side only handles is the controls (movement, actions etc.), and all stat tracking and computation is handled on the server side. That way, the only fake data the client can send is user actions. Don't use the client side to track the stats of the user, only use it to display the stats.

Comment: How is this possible exactly?

Comment: for a very basic example, imagine a tick tack toe game where the user can view their wins / losses. The client can only send their moves to the server, the server validates those moves and makes sure they are legal, and the server also handles logging when the game is over, and writing the result to the DB. In this way, the client can only view their stats, but has no control over setting them.